# K8S RBAC role to allow everything except namespaces and service accounts

Tags: kubernetes

Consider the RBAC role below. Is it possible to write a more sophisticated regex for `resources:` that prevents access to service accounts and namespaces but allows everything else?

```
- apiGroups:
  "*"
  resources:
  "*"
  verbs:
  "*"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "prevents access to namespaces" - should the role prevent creation fo namespaces or should it be scoped to particular namespace and prevent access to another namespaces?

Comment: I want to prevent CRUD operations on namespaces and service accounts

Comment: Did you manage to solve the case ?

Comment: I found a way around this :

List of objects will be these two commands
 kubectl api-resources --namespaced=true       

 kubectl api-resources --namespaced=false     

from there we form the list

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround for it is to disable possibility to access resources within namespace. Execute command:

```
$ kubectl api-resources --namespaced=false
```

Non-namespaced resources will be returned, otherwise returning namespaced resources by default.

Also while you are using:

- apiGroups:
  "*"  - this means that you want to grant access for all groups within Kubernetes API (both core API gorups and named groups )
- resources:
  "*" - this means that you want to grant access for all resources  (get, services, endpoints etc.)
- verbs:
  "*" - this means that you want to allow operations on specified objects (get, list, edit etc.).

In your case as you defined you don't prevent access but give it to every object etc.

Take a look on: [api-resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#api-resources).